# Which C# version can we upgrade to while retaining runtime compatibility with C# 2.0?

Tags: c#

We have a module for EpiServer which is written in C# 2.0 which we are continuing to develop. If the only thing we know about our customers is that our current module works fine, which version of C# may we upgrade to which will still work with the customers' current runtime?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All versions of the C# compiler after 2.0 can be used to target the 2.0 CLR / Runtime.  This is called down targeting.  The compiler will only let you use features supported on the previous version of the runtime and will provide errors if you attempt to use features that are not.  For example using dynamic when targeting 2.0.

Comment: But that's still going to force him into using C# 2.0 in the end, isn't it?

Comment: @Justin, not at all.  You can use virtually every feature of C# 3.0 on the 2.0 runtime.  Using LINQ requires a helper library like LINQBridge but once used, full LINQ to object querys can be written.  The only feature I know won't work is expression trees and that's due to CLR issues in 2.0RTM.

Comment: @Justin, No, you can then still use new features that do not require runtime support. For example, the "var" keyword (type inference), would then be usable, as this is entirely done at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The CLR version hasn't changed since 2005, it is still the 2.0 version.  That's about to change, 4.0 will be released in the spring.

Your only other consideration is what .NET assemblies you take a dependency on.  Stuff like WPF, WCF and Linq isn't likely to be available if your customer got stuck at the .NET 2.0 release.  You can easily avoid creating such a dependency in VS2008.  Project + Properties, Application tab, Target Framework combo.

Answer (score 0):

3 and 3.5 shuold work fine!

Answer (score 0):

C# isn't the runtime; it is the language. You need to be **very** clear about which you mean.

Targetting .NET 2.0:

You can use VS2008 and C# 3.0 to target .NET 2.0, including using all the C# 3.0 language features such as LINQ via things like LINQBridge. You should not, however, that you might accidentally take a reference to .NET 2.0 SP1 runtime features (`TimeZoneInfo` ?), or bugs/ "features", so you should test on the *actual* target framework.

Targetting C# 2.0:

If you want language compatibility, you can set this in the project (disabling C# 3.0 features), but again this isn't 100% - it will miss some things like type-inferencing enhancements; the following is fine in C# 3.0 but not C# 2.0, yet compiles with ISO-2 enabled:

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3};
string[] arr2 = Array.ConvertAll(arr, delegate (int i) {return i.ToString();});
```